# How send Lwin shortcut key in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Can someone tell mew how to send Shortcut keys in vb.net? The shortcut keys are {LEFTWIN} + {ADD} amd {LEFTWIN} + {SUBTRACT}. Tried SendKeys.Send it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sending `LWin` is not possible through `SendKeys.Send()`. In order to do so you have to P/Invoke the WinAPI's [**`SendInput()` function**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310(v=vs.85).aspx).

Here's a wrapper class I've created for that purpose:

> **EDIT (2019-09-20)**
>
> `InputHelper` has since long been moved to its own library. The answer has been updated to reflect this change.
>
> **Download InputHelper from GitHub:**
>   https://github.com/Visual-Vincent/InputHelper/releases

Here's how you'd use it:

```
InputHelper.Keyboard.SetKeyState(Keys.LWin, True) 'Hold LWin.
InputHelper.Keyboard.PressKey(Keys.Add) 'Press the ADD key.
InputHelper.Keyboard.SetKeyState(Keys.LWin, False) 'Release LWin.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy :)

Answer (score 2):

Finally this worked for me :)

```
Private Declare Sub keybd_event Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal bVk As IntPtr, ByVal bScan As IntPtr, ByVal dwFlags As IntPtr, ByVal dwExtraInfo As IntPtr)
Private Const VK_STARTKEY = &H5B
Private Const VK_SUBTRACT = &H6D
Private Const VK_ADD = &H6B
Private Const VK_ESCAPE = &H1B
Private Const KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = &H2
Private Const KEYEVENTF_KEYDOWN = &H

Call keybd_event(VK_STARTKEY, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYDOWN, 0)
Call keybd_event(VK_ADD, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYDOWN, 0)
Call keybd_event(VK_ADD, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0)
Call keybd_event(VK_STARTKEY, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0)
```

Key codes: http://vbcity.com/cfs-filesystemfile.ashx/__key/CommunityServer.Components.PostAttachments/00.00.11.85.52/Api.txt

**EDIT** 
The keybd_event is deprecated so I am moving to SendInput(). The first solution works best for me :-)

Comment: Nice, but I have two notes: **A)** The `Call` keyword is unnecessary. **B)** The `keybd_event()` function is deprecated and replaced by `SendInput()`, so it might get removed in the future.

Comment: Thanks for informing. I will go with SendInput() then.

Comment: No problem. It was good and nice that you found your own solution, however some set of posts/tutorials out there are starting to get outdated. -- By the way the `VK_` keys are mapped to the [`System.Windows.Forms.Keys` enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys(v=vs.110).aspx), so you wouldn't have had to copy the `VK_` declarations to your code either. (:

Comment: And just because I like to verify all my statements, here's a quote from the [**`keybd_event()` documentation**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646304(v=vs.85).aspx): `Note:  This function has been superseded. Use SendInput instead.`

Answer (score -4):

You said you tried

```
 SendKeys.Sned("KEY")
```

The correct is

```
 SendKeys.Send("KEY")
```

Besides that, what key you are referring with "Leftwin" ?

## Edited:

Sorry for that, I never used Sendkeys, and I knew "LWIN" by Winkey...

Btw, Try using

```
SendKeys.Send(Keys.LWin)
```

SendKeys send string, so this SendKeys.Send(Keys.LWin) actually should send the code of Keys.LWin

Comment: I think he just misspelled the function when he wrote the question. By the way, _LWin_ or _LeftWin_ is the [left windows key](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_key).

Comment: Since `SendKeys.Send()` takes a string (as you say) the enumeration you are passing is either going to be converted into "LWin" (which will result in it typing "LWin" character by character) or it will be converted into the string representation of the enumeration value (which is 91) and send that character by character instead. -- The `SendKeys.Send()` method does not take key codes for input. It simply parses the inputted string into _an array of key codes_ which it then passes along to WinAPI functions that will perform the key strokes. There simply is no way to send LWin using `SendKeys`.