# Global hotkey not registered in game using GetAsyncKeyState - vb.net

Tags: vb.net, while-loop, global, repeat, pressed

I've made a tool that will continuously click for the user if they decide to have it on with toggle keys etc, it all works fine in ordinary windows e.g google chrome, but when it comes to games it doesn't always work correctly.
(well it does in some games, then others it doesn't)

The code is designed to click fast while holding LButton, then stop when it's let go to act as an autoclicker (user has control of speed) which again works, but when in a game it clicks alot slower than it's suppose to / any other window / app.

I've figured out adding a delay using

```
         Thread.Sleep(200)
```

fixes the speed of the autoclicker in game, but then it messes up the keybind which results in the autoclicker always clicking even when LButton isnt held / pressed.

Is there anything else that I could use as a delay, or anything else I can do to the code so it works correctly?

I've been trying many different variations and searching online the last few days trying to get it working, but none succeeded.

Here's all the code got to do with autoclicking in my project, i've added some notes to try and explain which part is doing what / speeds the timers are set to.

```
    Imports System.Threading

    Public Class Form1
    Private Declare Function GetAsyncKeyState Lib "user32" (ByVal vkey As    Integer) As Short
    Private Declare Sub mouse_event Lib "user32" (ByVal dwflags As Integer,   ByVal dx As Integer, ByVal cbuttons As Integer, ByVal dy As Integer, ByVal   dwExtraInfo As Integer)
    Private Const mouseclickup = 4
    Private Const mouseclickdown = 2

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles   MyBase.Load

    'Timer1 isnt doing the clicking, Timer1 is just listening for LButton  
    'clicks which is why I have it always on aswell as a low interval.
    Timer1.Start()
    Timer1.Interval = 1

    'LButton is the timer that will do the clicking.
    LButton.Interval = 100
    End Sub

    Private Sub LButton_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles  LButton.Tick

    If GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.LButton) Then
        mouse_event(mouseclickup, 0, 0, 0, 0)

        'Without Thread.Sleep(200) the code works as it's suppose to, clicks 
        'when LButton is held, stops clicking when LButton is let go, 
        'although without Thread.Sleep(200) it will not work in all games, 
        'but with it, it will continuously click even when LButton isn't held.
        Thread.Sleep(200)

        mouse_event(mouseclickdown, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    Else
        LButton.Stop()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

    'This is what will listen for the left clicks and also stop the left
    'LButton timer if LButton is not held 

    If GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.LButton) Then
        LButton.Start()
    Else
        LButton.Stop()
    End If

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: `GetAsyncKeyState()` is known to not work in fullscreen applications such as most games. The recommended solution is usually creating a keyboard hook.

Comment: @VisualVincent The game im having an issue with runs in desktop/windowed mode and isn't steam, the issue is it's pressing down lbutton and releasing it too quickly for the game to register the command thats why adding the Thread Sleep command made it click the speed it's suppose to, but then the keybind messes up (it continues to click even when lbutton isnt held) so then i thought changing the delay would help, since its stopping / putting the thread to sleep, it doesnt remember the starting code where if left is held to click, else stop.  Is there anything else i could use as a delay?

Comment: The problem is that `GetAsyncKeyState()` returns non-zero values in different states (e.g. key down, key up, etc.), so your code _will_ fire multiple times. To stop this, check for key down and then make a loop that iterates until `GetAsyncKeyState()` returns zero. -- What I am talking about can be found in one of my [**previous answers**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38154826/3740093). -- I'll write an answer to you shortly.

Comment: @VisualVincent I've looked at your previous answer but i'm not really sure how to use it.  I'm going to keep trying although if you could help me out I would really appreciate it.  I've spent all week trying to create this tool, each time I take a step forward I take one back and is just becoming very time consuming, but now that i've started and designed the layout I don't want to quit on it just yet.

Comment: Hang in there! One answer is about to be posted!

Comment: You have to excuse the delay, but some things happened that I had to take care of before finishing the answer. Hope it helps!

Comment: I haven't noticed until now, but are you really supposed to send `mouseclickup` _before_ you send `mouseclickdown`? Usually it's the other way around; the mouse button is down when you press it, and up when you release it. I believe once this code stops it'll cause your mouse button to be in a "down" state until you click it again manually.

Comment: @VisualVincent Yes that seems to be what the problem is, when it continuously clicks, it stops once I press LButton again, although when I have mouseclickdown before mouseclickup it doesn't do any clicking at all.  I've been experimenting with that the last few days.  What I also noticed is when I have a different button to do the clicking, e.g keys.R instead of keys.LButton it works perfectly no matter what mouse event comes first, but I need the activator to be keys.LButton.

Comment: `it doesn't do any clicking at all` - Well that's likely because you already hold the button down when the code tries to send a mouse down, however after the first programmatic mouse up it should work all the following times. -- If swapping them doesn't work, consider sending a mouse up when you sense the button being released (i.e. when you stop the timer).

Comment: @VisualVincent - Isn't that the problem i'm having? The code isn't registering when LButton is released since it continues to click by itself, otherwise the timer would stop automatically which would stop the clicking.

Comment: You're right. I never saw that problem actually... Well I don't know if there's a solution to that. I think the `mouse_event()` and `SendInput()` functions pushes input to same stream that `GetAsyncKeyState()` checks. The only possible solutions/workarounds I can think of is **A)** Limiting how many clicks it sends, or **B)** Reading the raw mouse input (if it is not affected by `mouse_event()` or `SendInput()`).

Comment: @VisualVincent - I would like to thank you for at least trying and the time you spent trying to help me, what i'm trying to make is possible as there's many programs out there that does this, just perhaps not in vb.net.  Reasoning i'm trying to make my own is to have my own options / features that I find useful that're not in the others.  I'm going to have a look at C++ and see if I run into the same problems.

Comment: Thank you! It's my pleasure! I know how grueling it can be when you're stuck at something. -- Do you know C++ better than VB.NET? Actually very little hardware control is possible in the .NET languages... It's possible that the `GetRawInputData()` or `GetRawInputDataBuffer()` functions could do what you want, and they should (like any other WinAPI function) be P/Invokable in VB.NET. I would've tried it if I just had had the time...

Comment: Maybe [**this article**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645546(v=vs.85).aspx) can help.

Comment: @VisualVincent Turns out C++ is harder than I expected, but I thought of a new workaround, what if I have keys.LMenu activate the clicking which works perfectly(Starts clicking when held, stops when let go), and then when keys.LButton is held to sendkeys.send("%")? I've tried it out, but each time I hold Lbutton, it only sends LAlt once, any ideas why?

Comment: Well C++ is a low-level language, compiled directly into machine code. Low-level languages usually are much more complicated. -- I don't know why it only presses `LAlt` once, but instead of `SendKeys` try [this answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39804079/how-send-lwin-shortcut-key-in-vb-net/39811354#39811354).

Comment: @VisualVincent - That worked, and almost fixed my problem, it will work if I change the in-game Lbutton bind to LAlt, then by holding Lbutton it will click.  As a last resort this will be fine, and will definitely be usable for what I want it for, when I have time i'll probably be able to figure out how to do it without having to change the in-game bind key, i'm just pretty tired right now.  Thanks for all of your help!

Comment: No problem! This has been educational! I read about the `GetRawInputData/-Buffer` functions and found out they require a window to read `WM_INPUT` messages. This means that they would only work if the mouse interacts with that specific window, so once it goes outside the window would stop receiving the messages. Apparently it's much harder than I thought to read raw mouse input...

Answer (score 0):

Quoting [**the MSDN documentation**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646293(v=vs.85).aspx), `GetAsyncKeyState()` determines:

> whether a key is up or down at the time the function is called, and whether the key was pressed after a previous call to GetAsyncKeyState.

So when you check the function via `If GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.LButton) Then`, it will return non-zero at least three times, thus execute the code more than you want (which is what you experience when you add `Thread.Sleep(200)`).

To check if the key is held down you have to check if [**the most significant bit**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_significant_bit) is set, which for a `Short` is `0x8000` in hex and `32768` in decimal.

Checking a bit flag is done by checking `(<number> And <bit>) = <bit>` - where `And` is the [**bitwise `And` operator**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz3k228a.aspx).

This would result in your code looking like this:

```
Const KeyDownBit As Integer = &H8000

Private Sub LButton_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles  LButton.Tick
    If (GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.LButton) And KeyDownBit) = KeyDownBit Then
        mouse_event(mouseclickup, 0, 0, 0, 0)
        Thread.Sleep(200)
        mouse_event(mouseclickdown, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    Else
        LButton.Stop()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    If (GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.LButton) And KeyDownBit) = KeyDownBit Then
        LButton.Start()
    Else
        LButton.Stop()
    End If
End Sub
```

I'm not sure whether your second timer (`Timer1`) is actually needed in this case.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and the time that you're putting into this helping me, although I still have the same problem, it just becomes un-responsive and continues to click, sometimes it will stop when LButton is released, but then other times it continues to click.

Comment: Removing Thread.Sleep(200) makes it responsive, but then without Thread.Sleep(200) the clicking speed is extremely slow for what it's suppose to be (same speed no matter what the interval is set to)

Comment: @Joey : It becomes unresponsive because `Thread.Sleep()` is a blocking call. It blocks the entire thread, which is the User Interface (UI) thread since you're using a normal `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`. Use a new thread or a task to take the load of the user interface.

Comment: @Joey : As for the problem with it not stopping, I'd have to test the code to say for sure what's going on... What I can advice you to do is to run two threads/tasks (the UI and one background thread could work) where one thread checks for clicks and the other performs `mouse_event()` calls until the first one tells it to stop.

Comment: I'm not sure if I followed correctly (i'm new to vb.net), so I made two forms, I have mouse_event() on one form that does the clicking, then another form where GetAsyncKeyState checks for the clicks and activates the other forms timer if Lbutton is held, else stop the timer.  I'm not sure if that's what you were telling me to do, but unfortunately that doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: @Joey : That's not exactly what I'm telling you, but you've got the principle. A form is just a window that's owned by the UI thread, whereas an actual [**Thread**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computing)) is used to execute code concurrently (the term for this is _multithreading_). I'll do some testing before I update my answer, but I believe it should work (without the code running concurrently it wouldn't however, which is why you need two different threads).

Comment: @Joey : If the first thread uninterruptedly checks for clicks it can control whether the second thread should distribute clicks via a `Boolean` variable. If the variable is `True` the second thread will distribute clicks, once the first thread stops sensing that you're holding the button it will set the variable to `False`, thus causing the second thread to stop distributing more clicks.