# How to simulate spacebar in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I Have

```
Private Declare Sub keybd_event Lib "user32" (ByVal bVk As Byte, ByVal bScan As Byte, ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Long)
Private Const KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = &H2
Public Enum KeyDef
    VK_SPACE = &H20
End Enum
     If My.Computer.Keyboard.AltKeyDown Then
        keybd_event(&H20, 0, 0, 0)
        keybd_event(&H20, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0)
     End If
```

And I want it to simulate the spacebar being pressed when the alt key is pressed. However I get a "PInvokeStackImbalance:" Error whenever i press the alt key.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? Are you trying to "type" a space into a specific edit box or do you want just do whatever the space bar would do at that time regardless of what it might be? Basically, please provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem.

Comment: You can use my [**`InputHelper` class**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39804079/how-send-lwin-shortcut-key-in-vb-net/39811354#39811354).

Comment: It is a VB6 declaration, use a [VB.NET declaration instead](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/keybd_event.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there has been no activity in regards to your question, here is an easier way to simulate the spacebar key being pressed when the alt key is pressed. 
 First go to Nuget and download the package `Input Simulator` and add it to your project.
Once you have added it, `WindowsInput` should be available for you to import into your projects code. 
 See the example below.

```
Imports WindowsInput
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown
    Dim SIM = New WindowsInput.InputSimulator()
    If e.Alt = True Then
        SIM.Keyboard.KeyPress(WindowsInput.Native.VirtualKeyCode.SPACE)
        MessageBox.Show("ALT HAS BEEN PRESSED, SPACEBAR BUTTON PRESSED")
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

I believe that @Visual Vincent's comment is the way to go, however if you dont have much experience and just want a `quick fix`, this should be fine, you may need to change somethings around however this should hopefully get you on the right track.